# Likelihood Ratio test returns negative deviation

Tags: r, time-series, likelihood-ratio

I've ran the likelihood ratio test (statistc in 3rd row and p-value in 4th row) between the APARCH and the GJR. For some of the time series in analysis it returned a negative value for the test statistc of LR, as in X19, and consequently a p-value of 1.
The data under scrutinity are indexes as the S&P500 and the Russel 2000 between 2007-2016.
Is there any problem of getting a negative test statistic? In the literature I found some evidence that such phenomenon is not possible but it happened ...

[image]

Comment: The likelihood ratio test is not implemented correctly.

Comment: I have: LiklRatiotestGJRS <- -2*(lLGjS-lLAS); where: lLAS<−fit.compapARCH-std@fitLLH;lLGjS<−fit.compgjrGARCH-std@fit$LLH

Comment: Can you help me understand where is the problem?